# Awaiting Task.Run with async method does not throw exception on correct thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous

When running the test method below, I found that even though I await a task that throws an exception, the test passes. Furthermore, a separate window pops up saying "QTAgent.exe has stopped working". This indicates that the exception is not propagated to the thread running the test and instead kills a separate thread.

I would like to know why this happens. Also, since this doesn't appear to work as intended, how should I run an async method on a thread pool thread?

Note that if I change it so that if func is not async, the exception is thrown in the test thread as expected.

```
 [TestMethod]
 public async Task TestWeirdTaskBehavior()
 {
      Action func = async () =>
      {
           await Task.Delay(0);
           throw new InvalidOperationException();
      };
      await Task.Run(func);
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple tweak:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestWeirdTaskBehavior()
{
    Func<Task> func = async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(0);
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    };
    await Task.Run(func);
}
```

Your `Action` is essentially an `async void`. You need the compiler to spit out a `Task` for you if you want to await it or wrap it in another `Task`. In your original snippet the outer task (`Task.Run(...)`) completes as soon as the inner task hits the first `await`, *before* the exception is thrown.

Comment: Wow! Just wasted half a day on this one. I've tried several threads on SO and other sites but no joy. Until finally I came across this little catch. It's a kind of thing that I would expect the compiler to spot. Many thanks!!